# neo4j-spatial in neo4j 2.0 sample data

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-spatial

Giving Neo4j 2.0 a go (from binaries, in windows) with the Hubway Data Challenge dataset from the Neo4j website. All loaded fine in 2.0 (setting the `allow_store_upgrade=true`).

Looking at the graph/data in the Neo browser interface it seems that this particular dataset uses featues in the neo4j-spatial plugin. The plugins directory is empty, apart from the README file but the browser interface shows spatial `layer, geometries, RTREE_ROOT` relationship types and `geomencoder` etc property keys. Also, the properties, having clicked a node, show things like `org.neo4j.gis.spatial....`

If the plugins dir is empty, why do these entries exist in the graph? Does 2.0 have spatial built in? Please see the image below.[image: Hubway Data, Neo4j 2.0]

Answer (score 1):

The spatial features where used when building this dataset from Spring-Data-Neo4j using the spatial features. You can copy databases and the structure stays in there.

If you add the spatial plugin to your plugins directory you can also execute spatial cypher queries against that dataset.

Things like these: http://neo4j.github.io/spatial/#rest-api-find-geometries-in-a-bounding-box-using-cypher

Comment: Ok, that's interesting. With regards to spatial in 2.0, having spent a while trying to get it to work a couple of weeks bak (using the Cypher and REST in the link you provide), [issue #127](https://github.com/neo4j/spatial/issues/127) prevented spatial working in 2.0 as there is no root node?